# Output from more processes than specified in arguments

Tags: c, mpi

I am new to mpi and rerunning the code given here : http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-hello-world/

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

// Initialize the MPI environment
MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

// Get the number of processes
int world_size;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

// Get the rank of the process
int world_rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

// Get the name of the processor
char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
int name_len;
MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

// Print off a hello world message
printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d out of %d processors\n",
       processor_name, world_rank, world_size);

// Finalize the MPI environment.
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Compiling that using `mpicc -o mpi_hello_world mpi_hello_world.c` and running `mpiexec -np 4 ./mpi_hello_world`

I expect similar results given on the webpage

```
Hello world from processor cetus2, rank 1 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor cetus1, rank 0 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor cetus4, rank 3 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor cetus3, rank 2 out of 4 processors
```

But instead of getting output from 4 processes, I get from 24. It is something like this.

```
Hello world from processor cetus3, rank <n> out of 24 processors
```

`n` is from 0 to 23. I am using linux cluster remotely. Similar result using `mpirun`. If I specify `np - 36`, I get the same result for 24 processes. Can someone tell what is going wrong?

Comment: Your code give the expected output when I run it on my machine.  You will need to give some more details about your setup (os, mpi version) to help find the problem

Comment: does it say 'rank X out of 24 processors' ? try `mpiexec -n 4 ./mpi_hello_world` and/or `mpirun -np 4 ./mpi_hello_world`.

Comment: @ptb updated the question.

Comment: Your code is fine but something is wrong with the mpi/os/scheduler setup.  I would suggest talking to your cluster admin.  To gather more data points, you could find and run an mpi test suite for the implementation you are using.

Comment: which MPI library (vendor & version) ? are you runing under a batch manager ? which one ? can you copy/paste both your command line and (trimmed) output ? `np - 36` does not make sense here, it would be `mpirun -np 36 ./mpi_hello_world`.